# login with rsa to my vps

Tags: ssh, debian, vps, putty, rsa

I successfully added a rsa key my root account.
since I don't want everything in my root acc, I created a new user. but for some how, I keep getting "server refuses our keys" message :S

I did following command with my root acc:

```
adduser kossel
usermod -a -G sudo kossel
groups kossel
mkdir /home/kossel/.ssh
vi /home/kossel/.ssh/authorized_keys

//I pasted the key in this format "ssh-rsa xxxxxxxxxxxxxx==" for putty openSSH compatibility reason

chown -R kossel:kossel /home/kossel/.ssh
chmod 700 /home/kossel/.ssh
chmod 600 /home/kossel/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

am I missing something?

**update:**
answering comments:
I have successfully done modifying the puttygen public key to suit openSSH, because my root acc is working.

I checked /var/log/auth.log the only message i got is:

```
Sep 12 15:59:40 9port sshd[7714]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user kossel
Sep 12 15:59:52 9port sshd[7739]: reverse mapping checking getaddrinfo for dsl-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-dyn.prod-ISPDOMAIN.com [my_ip_address] failed - POSSIBLE BREAK-IN ATTEMPT!
```

ps: and I also got some spam user already trying to login??
sorry I just started to use vps yesterday.

Comment: 1. Is it (your public key) all one line? 2. Post your `/var/log/auth.log`?

Comment: it looks like the format of keys is not recognized by your SSH server... I've heard something about Putty SSH keys which need to be converted to an appropriate format, although I have never had such trouble with my putty clients/linux servers. I have then never done any change from putty keys for openssh compaibility. Can you post your /var/log/auth.log while attempting to perform a connection?
One more point: usually the format is ssh-rsa xxxx user@machine, the '==' are part of the key

Comment: Ah! And maybe the key length is not enough for your ssh server. I would advise never less than 1024 bits.

Comment: _I have successfully done modifying the puttygen public key to suit openSSH_ --> how did you edit your public key for compatibility with `ssh-keygen`?

Comment: following this: https://www.walkernews.net/2009/03/22/how-to-fix-server-refused-our-key-error-that-caused-by-putty-generated-rsa-public-key/, basically just trim the key into one line

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try copying your original public key normally (that generated by `puttygen`), and then convert it to an OpenSSH compatible format:

```
ssh-keygen -i -f puttygen.ppk > ssh-keygen.pub
```

---

**UPDATE**

`puttygen` supports exporting your key to an OpenSSH format, try this:

[image]

Comment: I got "uudecode failed." message O_o

Comment: sounds like it is already in OpenSSH format or your public key has DOS-style line break.

Comment: @Kossel: updated my question.

Comment: does the public key has to be some specific name like "Authorized keys" or it can be any just under ~/.ssh folder?

Comment: You mean on the server? If so, it must be `authorized_keys`.

Comment: it worked! I think the other reason is I misspelled the word "authorized_keys"